# Invoke-Command executable doesn't work when parameter passed instead of text

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting, invoke-command

I'm building a parameterized script to pass a server name and a string parameter to pass to an executable on that server.  Script is as follows with issue described after:

```
#Set up server and AC parameters
param(
  [string]$DBServer = "stvsqld08",
  [string]$ACString = "Our Personnel"
)

#Set up new session object for accessing production
$sess = New-PSSession -Computer $DBserver

#Execute AC ----DOES NOT WORK
Invoke-Command -Session $sess -ScriptBlock {
  param($scriptACString)
  & 'C:\Program Files (x86)\LexisNexis\InterAction\IAAppCol\INTIATBC.EXE' $scriptACString
} -Args $ACString 

#---------DOES WORK
Invoke-Command -Session $sess -ScriptBlock {
  param($scriptACString)
  & 'C:\Program Files (x86)\LexisNexis\InterAction\IAAppCol\INTIATBC.EXE' Our Personnel
}
```

You'll see in the "DOES WORK" command I hard code the text parameter sent to the executable.  In "DOES NOT WORK" I'm trying to pass this value as a string parameter, but it doesn't work.

**UPDATE**
If we take the remote execution out of the picture and just execute this on the console it still doesn't work.  As i understand it the two call operator executions should be identical.  The hard coded one successfully calls the executable with the parameter.  The parameterized one fails to successfully call the executable with the parameter.

```
PS C:\Users\mp071663_e> $ACString = "Our Personnel"
PS C:\Users\mp071663_e> write-host $ACString
Our Personnel
PS C:\Users\mp071663_e> & 'C:\Program Files (x86)\LexisNexis\InterAction\IAAppCol\INTIATBC.EXE' Our Personnel
PS C:\Users\mp071663_e> & 'C:\Program Files (x86)\LexisNexis\InterAction\IAAppCol\INTIATBC.EXE' $ACString
```

Comment: What do you mean by "DOES NOT WORK"? The only difference I can see, is that in first case `Our Personnel` will be enclosed in quotes when passed to native application, but that not related to `Invoke-Command` at all.

Comment: It does nothing.  No error messages.  The executable on the server isn't run properly.  When I run the "DOES WORK" it processes 5 rows associated to that string i submit.  When i run "DOES NOT WORK" the 5 rows are not processed.

Comment: Does it work, if you invoke this on target computer directly? Does it work, if you pass `Our Personnel` as a single string (`'Our Personnel'`) and not as two strings as in your second case?

Comment: Executing invoke-command -session $sess -ScriptBlock {param($scriptACString)& 'C:\Program Files (x86)\LexisNexis\InterAction\IAAppCol\INTIATBC.EXE' 'Our Personnel'} also does nothing.

Comment: If I try to execute the ps1 on the target server it still does nothing--only the "DOES WORK" line executes properly.  I don't understand why invoke-command treats the hard coded text differently than the parameter....?  For context here is the command line that executes correctly on the server:
C:\Program Files (x86)\LexisNexis\InterAction\IAAppCol> INTIATBC.EXE Our Personnel

Comment: Does it work, if you execute `INTIATBC.EXE 'Our Personnel'` on server?

Comment: Doesn't work that way locally or on the server.

Comment: So, you problem not related to `Invoke-Command`. Problem in that PowerShell generate different command line for `INTIATBC.EXE 'Our Personnel'` and for `INTIATBC.EXE 'Our' 'Personnel'`.

Comment: Well, it appears that the one without single or double quotes is the functional one.  passing ****INTIATBC.EXE Our Personnel **** works.  ****INTIATBC.EXE 'Our Personnel' **** and ****INTIATBC.EXE "Our Personnel" **** do not work.  I just don't understand why passing in the text as a parameter removes the functionality.  If i do a write-host $ACString it shows me the parameter without any single or double quotes.  So it must be how it's delivering it to the remote server...  I just don't get what the difference is.

Comment: can you try to check if your parameter is being sent to Invoke-Command printing the variable passed instead of execute your code? I know you passed it with args parameter I just want to confirm if it's being sent. after that we can go further debugging this code.

Comment: @AndrewBilbrey You yourself see same behavior running command locally. Why do you continue to say *it must be how it's delivering it to the remote server*? **It does not related to `Invoke-Command` at all.** You ran two different commands and get two different results. In one command you pass `Our Personnel` as single string: `$a='Our Personnel';INTIATBC.EXE $a`. In other command you pass two separate strings `Our` and `Personnel`: `$b='Our';$c='Personnel';INTIATBC.EXE $b $c`. And, as `Our Personnel` contains space, PowerShell add quotes around the string when passing it to `INTIATBC.EXE`.

Comment: @FelicioBalane - It's being sent.  It's not a prob with Invoke-Command.

Comment: @PetSerAl - First: thanks for explaining what you meant that powershell was putting quotes around the parameter with a space in it.  When i split it into tokens that worked.
Second: you'll see from my update up top that I already recognized it wasn't coming from Invoke-Command.  I'm green to powershell.  Chill, dude!  :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @PetSerAl this was narrowed to an issue with powershell putting quotes around a parameter with a space in it when it was passing it.  Typically this isn't an issue with executables.  Unfortunately, this executable rejects parameters with quotes.  So to be able to pass the single parameter that had spaces in it i set up 10 parameters that can be used and then are placed in order when passed in invoke-command.  Please see final script below that is functional.  Any further suggestions are greatly appreciated.

```
#Set up server and AC parameters
param([string]$DBServer, [string]$ACString1, [string]$AcString2, [string]$ACString3, [string]$ACString4, [string]$ACString5, [string]$ACString6, [string]$ACString7, [string]$ACString8, [string]$ACString9, [string]$ACString10)



#clean out any derelict sessions
try
{
Remove-PSSession $DBServer
}
catch
{
write-host $DBServer had no open sessions
}


#Set up new session object for accessing production
$sess = new-pssession -computer $DBserver

#Execute AC
#invoke-command -session $sess -ScriptBlock {param($scriptACString)& 'C:\Program Files (x86)\LexisNexis\InterAction\IAAppCol\INTIATBC.EXE' Our Personnel/Personnel Bus Addr}  -args $ACString 
invoke-command -session $sess -ScriptBlock {param($a, $b, $c, $d, $e, $f, $g, $h, $i, $j)& 'C:\Program Files (x86)\LexisNexis\InterAction\IAAppCol\INTIATBC.EXE' $a, $b, $c, $d, $e, $f, $g, $h, $i, $j} -ArgumentList($ACString1, $AcString2, $AcString3, $AcString4, $AcString5, $AcString6, $AcString7, $AcString8, $AcString9, $AcString10)
```

Comment: In PowerShell v5 your command will produce `Our,Personnel`. If you targeting on v3+, then I would use `INTIATBC.EXE '--%' $a`. And for v2 you can pass single array instead of bunch of parameters.